# Python Create Timeout for subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm writing a Python script that will refresh a Git repository, then build it.
The script is to be run daily (e.g. running on a daily build server).

The issue is that git commands to our server sometimes never complete (ok, I terminate the processes after 10 minutes or more).

I would like to set a Timeout for the subprocess (and probably put into a retry loop).
How do I set up the Timeout for a subprocess.

Here's my code so far:

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#   Script to daily build Voyant 3
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
import subprocess
import os

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#   Main program starts here.
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
repo_dir = "c:/sandboxes/git/voyant-3"

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#   Change to repo (repository) folder.
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
os.chdir(repo_dir);

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#   Refresh the repo (sandbox)
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
subprocess.run(["git", "fetch", "--all]"]);
```

*Notes:*

1. Using Python 27  (preferred) or Python 36
2. Using Windows 10 (The script will be registered as a service on the PC)
3. Research on using PyGit is not impressive; most Users say to use Python Subprocess.
4. From the Python documentation: (https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html):

> subprocess.run(args, *, stdin=None, input=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, capture_output=False, shell=False, cwd=None, timeout=None, check=False, encoding=None, errors=None, text=None, env=None, universal_newlines=None, **other_popen_kwargs)

Comment: set `timeout` parameter and catch the `TimeoutExpired` error?

Comment: As an alternative, you could use the `timeout` command, which can also do the "TERM, then KILL" sequence; `subprocess.run(["timeout", "-k30", "600", "git", "fetch", "--all"])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while True:
    try: subprocess.run(["git", "fetch", "--all"], timeout=600);
    except subprocess.TimeoutExpired: continue
    break
```